# Does exist a standard protocol for network printers?

Tags: printing, network-protocols, network-printers

Does exist a standard protocol for network printers? Some network printers require the installation of drivers to be used... Is there some network printer that can be used without installing additional drivers? After all, when we connect the network cable from the laptop to the router, we do not need to install drivers (any operating system already includes the driver).

Are there any open source projects related to protocols for communication with a network printer?

Comment: All printers require *some* form of driver: what to send to get it to print the image as intended. Getting the packets/job control to the printer is another (possibly related) issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard protocols are the [LPD](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1179.txt) or [IPP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911) protocols.

If you need to talk to a printer over the network, you can either attach it to a device that translates packets into USB/LPT commands, or attach it to a linux/windows PC and print through an LPD service running on that OS.

Comment: Your answer is wrong on so many accounts. Why toot LPD and IPP as 'standard protocols' and not telling encom83, that not all printers do support that standard, IPP? And why first declare IPP as 'standard' but then limit your 'print through a service' to LPD only? --

Comment: Also, it is obviously clear that enzom83 is not aware of *all* the tasks a printer driver on Windows needs to get done. The *protocol* level for transfering the bytes to the printer is the least of them. The *data conversion* job (tranforming the specific application format {*.doc, *.xls, *.txt, *.jpeg, *.odt,...} to the specific printer format {PostScript, PCL, ESC/P, PDF, AFP, TIFF, ...}) is more specific and more complicated...

Comment: ...however, I'll **NOT** -1 your answer :-)

Comment: Kurt, thank you for your comments.  In my defense, may I point out: 1. notice the word **or** between the LPD and IPP references 2. brief, two-sentence answers might not be wrong if they neglect to dive into wikipedia-level details

Comment: It is obvious that a printer must first convert the data into a specific format and then send the converted data to the printer.
If the data format supported by the printers were unique/stardard, the drivers for the conversion may be preinstalled on all operating systems, so it would not be required to install additional drivers in order to use a new printer :-) This was the reason for my question.

Answer (score 0):

[IPP Everywhere](https://www.pwg.org/ipp/everywhere.html) tries to be what you are asking for.

> A PWG standard that allows personal computers and mobile devices to find and print to networked and USB printers without using vendor-specific software.